# Cant get sql value, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i found the error but i dont know why, the error is in  the sql statement, if i replace the hash variable with the actual value work for example, hash = "3" work but if i use the variable hash with the same value its not working ;(. I cant get the value of result, its the number 2 but in echo its not showing anything, and i dont understand why, its using fetch for get the value, is an array of 1 so should be [0] the number 2, but its not working,
FIXED the error was on whitespace on variable

```
      <?php  
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require("db.php");



    $hash = $_GET["hash"];




$sql23 = "SELECT * FROM `game` WHERE `hash` = '$hash'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$sql23))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
}
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}



    ;
    ?>
```

Comment: Should `echo $row['']."<br>";` be `echo $row['point']."<br>";` (i.e. name of column as index)

Comment: Don't mix two libraries.

Comment: ty but didnt worrk

Comment: Dude, check out my answer. You have many other mistakes.

Comment: Lemme know if it works...

Comment: @PraveenKumar - In what way does the OP mix two libraries?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I meant *don't mix OOP and procedure*.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - That's a bit different. But that doesn't really change anything, though. You _can_ mix procedural and OOP with mysqli. If you should, is another discussion, though :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Is it so? I didn't know about that. Wow. *goes to try that out*

Comment: @PraveenKumar - At any point, you can use `$link` as an object. However, for consistency, it's better to stick to either or. I would prefer the OOP way, since it makes the code easier to read and less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your code is terribly vulnerable to SQL Injection. Make sure you save your application from that. So for now, change it this way:

```
$hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET["hash"]);
$sql2 = "SELECT point FROM game WHERE hash='$hash'";
```

Secondly, your code here:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row['']."<br>";
}
echo $row[0];
```

Doesn't make any sense. You have to rewrite it this way by not assigning something in the `where` condition and also by checking for existence of rows before getting into the `where` loop and finally **don't mix OOP and procedure**:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
  while (false != ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
```

The above code will show you what fields are available. Most probably, the code you are looking for is:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
  while (false != ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    echo $row["point"], "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: not worrking   while (false != ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    echo $row["point"], "<br />";
  } its not showing nothing ;(

Comment: @atr Is it totally blank?

Comment: yes and the value of point is 2, if u execute the query on the sql web console give 2

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. You should use Prepared Statements.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Agreed, I don't know how to write PS, so I didn't write anything for now. This is far better than using nothing.

Comment: @atr If it's blank, it might be possibly a code error, and you have not enabled errors. Can you please enable errors and try?

Comment: @atr Can you edit your original question and add the latest full code?

Comment: done, here the database Database: game »Table: game, structure hash,point,sender

Comment: @atr Remove the last `;`. Seems like no errors in PHP.

Comment: @atr Give me some time to think. Will try to get a solution. `:(` I am confused as well...

Comment: sure me too ;(.

Comment: btw if i try to print $result get an error,  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string, this is because its not fetch row or some similiar and should work with $row but its not

Comment: just tried other sql query and its working, so the problem is here "SELECT point FROM game WHERE hash='$hash'" but i dont see where :(